# Ef code first one to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework

How o define one to many relationship in EF with different primary and foreign key name

**UPDATED**

```
Public class Tb1
{
[Key]
public int ID{get; set;}         // primary
**public int foreignKey{get; set;} //foreign key**
public string name{get; set;} 
[Foreign("foreignKey")]
public virtual ICollection<Tb2> Tb2{ get; set; }
}

Public class Tb2
{
[Key]
public int ID {get; set;} //primary
public int tb1ID {get; set}
public string address {get; set;} 
}
```

Here i want one to many relationsip on Primary key: foreignKey at TB1
                                            foreign kye: tb1ID at TB2

HOW??

Answer (score 1):

My Nomal approach would be to include the navigation property as well. So I would change Tb2 like this:

```
Public class Tb2
{
  [Key]
  public int ID {get; set;} //primary
  public int Tb1ID {get; set;} //notice I changed case on this variable as well
  public Tb1 Tb1 {get; set;} //this is the new variable
  public string address {get; set;} 
}
```

Code first should be able to automatically understand the relationship now. If you don't want the Tb1ID property, you can remove it, and it will still work out just fine.

Comment: When do you get null for it? When you fetch it from the database? If you are using code first with DbRepository, it does not lazy load it as you might expect. Try doing the following to get Tb2 with all related Tb1's. `var result = repository.Tb2s.Include( t => t.Tb1 );`

Comment: lazy loading was initially set to false db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: Ok, but when do you get it as null? Can you provide some code here so we can see the problem? Did `Tb1ID` have the correct value?